# PHP the variable set in main page is not accessible in included page

Tags: php

I m having trouble getting variable value in included file. please have a look at my code snippet below

I have following code in test.php

```
<?php
//this first block includes design.php and takes parameter from url string
ob_start();
require("includes/design.php");
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();



 //this second block includes same file but different variable is passed
    ob_start();

    $itemtest = "This is test";
    require("includes/design.php");
    $contents_orderslip = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ?>
```

and design.php has following codes

```
<?php

  echo "ITEM TEST = ".$itemtest;
  exit;
?>
```

When I execute test.php, the only thing that is getting printed is `ITEM TEST =`. Why I m not getting value for `$itemtest`

Thanks

Comment: are you including the design.php in test.php

Comment: yes some how my code in test.php is not displaying here in stackoverflow

Comment: @Aquillo, i m not using `$itemtest` in function. if i m using in function i need to use `global`

Comment: Actually, your code works, at least on the command line. Are you sure you're running `test.php` and not `design.php` directly?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Not just command line. The code actually works.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, yes i m running `test.php`

Comment: A typo seems the most plausible explanation at this point; add `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of `test.php` to highlight notices about undefined variables.

Comment: have you tried without the ob commands?

Comment: there has to be some error in the run time, if you change to `include_once` it will print the entire string.

Comment: @WatsMyName Post your real codes plz, the codes you posted won't lead to such result.

Comment: @WatsMyName If there are other code in `design.php`, make sure they did not rewrite `$itemtest`.

Comment: @xdazz please see my update, i have echoed at the very first line of `design.php` so no chance of getting rewrited

Comment: @WatsMyName Like my answer said, if you have `exit;` in `design.php`, the code execution will stop right after exit, so your second piece of code doesn't even run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `design.php` is saving to the variable `$contents_orderslip`.

Your code echo nothing, add the below as the last line:

```
echo $contents_orderslip;
```

**Update:**

Since you **edited** your code and add `exit;` to `design.php`, then execution will stop right there, but still you should get `$itemtest` defined because it's in the same global scope.

**Update2:**
The reason is clear when you **posted all of the code**.
If you have `exit;` in `design.php`, the code execution will stop right after `exit;`, so your second piece of code doesn't even run.

Comment: There is an `echo "ITEM TEST = ".$itemtest;` at `design.php`

Comment: @Downvoters First google what `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` do...

Comment: `well i only get "ITEM TEST = "` as output, why not getting the variable value then?

Comment: I agree the example does not work without the echo, however he is getting _some_ output so I'm assuming he is already outputting the value somehow.

Comment: "the only thing that is getting printed is ITEM TEST =" ... that can't be explained with wrong use of OB afaict.

Comment: @WatsMyName Post all of your codes with the whole context plz, by your code, it won't be that result.

Comment: @xdazz i have updated my code, please have a look it

Comment: @WatsMyName Now it's clear, right?

Comment: @WatsMyName That change made all the difference, now the question is actually answerable :) +1 to this.

Comment: @xdazz, yes its indeed now

Comment: @WatsMyName Your first code hurts my answer, next time remember to post code which can reproduce your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

since you have used `ob_start();` - it will halt anything being  displayed on the screen.

@xdazz is right - You need to use this, after the `ob_clean`:

```
echo $contents_orderslip;
```

You've basically stored all the output into this variable.

Comment: Then it wouldn't have echoed `ITEM TEST = ` either, would it?

Comment: And there's an `exit;` in `design.php`, so that will flush the buffers as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the first block of `test.php` you have not defined `$itemtest` yet. The code in `design.php` will therefore only print `ITEM TEST =` and, if you had enabled `error_reporting(-1)`, you would have seen a notice about an undefined variable.

The second block will not run at all because you have an `exit;` statement here:

```
echo "ITEM TEST = ".$itemtest;
exit;
```

That will flush the output buffers and halt the whole program. Removing that statement will make `$contents_orderslip` contain the following:

```
ITEM TEST = This is test
```

And `$content` will contain:

```
ITEM TEST =
```

Answer (score -2):

test.php

```
<?php
    $users = "Hello World You Buddy";
    require "defs.php";
?>
```

defs.php

```
<?php
     echo $users;
?>
```

works fine